# How to calculate throughput of flume in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, flume, throughput

How can i calculate the throughput of flume in my hadoop cluster ? I am doing this for the first time. 
All of my data that is written to HDFS is via flume.

I looked at a few charts in HDFS and found:  ***Total Bytes Written Across DataNodes*** seems to be around **2.2MB/s** avg for a 1 d period. is this correct and the way to go ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any distribution like HDP or CDH?. CDH provides a nice metrics when viewing the Flume Agent via Cloudera Manager. It provides the following 
Channel : put Ratio %, take Ratio %
Source: Event Receive Success per second
Sink: Event Drain success per second

I presume that is what you are looking for